# Extracting audio features like MFCC on android

Tags: java, android, mfcc, tarsosdsp, jaudiotagger

I want to extract MFCC from audio files on android. I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find any working code for this. Could someone share any working code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

[TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) contains an implementation of MFCC. Since version 2.0 TarsosDSP runs on Android.